# Problems with form api and #tree

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to create a form element with an array of child inputs. How is the below example incorrect in D7, I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects in C:\wamp\www\water-uk\www\includes\common.inc on line 6518

array(3) {
  '#tree' =>
  bool(true)
  '#type' =>
  string(8) "fieldset"
  'first' =>
  array(6) {
    '#type' =>
    string(6) "select"
    '#options' =>
    array(8) {
      'All' =>
      string(8) "Show all"
      [0] =>
      class stdClass#470 (1) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      class stdClass#468 (1) {
        ...
      }
      [2] =>
      class stdClass#469 (1) {
        ...
      }
    }
    '#size' =>
    NULL
    '#default_value' =>
    string(3) "All"
    '#ajax' =>
    array(5) {
      'callback' =>
      string(38) "_listing_blocks_select_tax_depth_js"
      'wrapper' =>
      string(18) "tax-select-wrapper"
      'method' =>
      string(6) "append"
      'effect' =>
      string(4) "fade"
      'event' =>
      string(6) "change"
    }
    '#required' =>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using `stdClass` objects for the values in your options array. Drupal expects a string for each of the options.

You probably have code like:

```
foreach ($something as $item) {
  // $item is a stdClass.
  $options[$item->key] = $item;
}
```

when you need to have something like

```
foreach ($something as $item) {
  // $item is a stdClass.
  $options[$item->key] = $item->name;
}
```

Comment: This is a views exposed form, and it is how the form is generated initially, it seems happy with the objects. BTW I have with standard key value pairs and have the same issue.

Comment: Gotcha. chx himself [says the error is due to a missing `#` key somewhere](http://drupal.org/node/53230#comment-385559), I'd check for that next